# flask-security login via username and not email

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I wanted to have the field in `User` model that through it the user logs in as `username` instead of `email`

I defined:
`app.config['SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES'] = 'username'`

But I'm still getting:

```
user_datastore.add_role_to_user(name, 'mgmt')
      File "/Users/boazin/sentinal/sentinel-cloud/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/datastore.py", line 105, in add_role_to_user
        user, role = self._prepare_role_modify_args(user, role)
      File "/Users/boazin/sentinal/sentinel-cloud/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/datastore.py", line 72, in _prepare_role_modify_args
        user = self.find_user(email=user)
      File "/Users/boazin/sentinal/sentinel-cloud/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/datastore.py", line 203, in find_user
        return self.user_model.query.filter_by(**kwargs).first()
      File "/Users/boazin/sentinal/sentinel-cloud/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1333, in filter_by
        for key, value in kwargs.items()]
      File "/Users/boazin/sentinal/sentinel-cloud/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 383, in _entity_descriptor
        (description, key)
    InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'flask_app.models.User'>' has no property 'email'
```

It seems that email is hardcoded into flask-security...

Can I change it?

**edit**:
The User Model (as requested in the comment):

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    token = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/models.html

Fields `id, email, password, active` is essential.So add

```
email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
```

Just add your custom `username` field along this.

Comment: and what do I put in email field?

Comment: you can set a dummy email if you not want to use it

Answer (score 18):

To **login with a username instead of an email address** (using Flask-Security 1.7.0 or higher), you can replace the `email` field with a `username` field in the `User` model

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

and update the `app` configuration.

```
app.config['SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES'] = 'username'
```

Next, to allow users to login using a username instead of an email, we will use the fact that the [LoginForm validation method](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/forms.py) assumes the user identity attribute is in the `email` form field.

```
from flask_security.forms import LoginForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class ExtendedLoginForm(LoginForm):
    email = StringField('Username', [InputRequired()])

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore,
                    login_form=ExtendedLoginForm)
```

This way, we can login using a username without rewriting the validation method or the login template. Of course, this is a hack and the more correct approach would be to add a custom `validate` method, which checks a `username` form field, to the `ExtendedLoginForm` class and to update the login template accordingly.

However, the approach above makes it easy to **login with a username or an email address**. To do this, define a user model with both a username and email field.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

and update the `app` configuration.

```
app.config['SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES'] = ('username','email')
```

Finally, create the custom login form.

```
from flask_security.forms import LoginForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class ExtendedLoginForm(LoginForm):
    email = StringField('Username or Email Address', [InputRequired()])

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore,
                    login_form=ExtendedLoginForm)
```

Now, when logging in, Flask-Security will accept an email or username in the email form field.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to implement login using either username or password by overwriting the login form:

```
class ExtendedLoginForm(LoginForm):
    email = StringField('Username or Email Address')
    username = StringField("Username")

    def validate(self):
    from flask_security.utils import (
        _datastore,
        get_message,
        hash_password,
    )
    from flask_security.confirmable import requires_confirmation
    if not super(LoginForm, self).validate():
        return False

    # try login using email
    self.user = _datastore.get_user(self.email.data)

    if self.user is None:
        self.user = _datastore.get_user(self.username.data)

    if self.user is None:
        self.email.errors.append(get_message("USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST")[0])
        # Reduce timing variation between existing and non-existing users
        hash_password(self.password.data)
        return False
    if not self.user.password:
        self.password.errors.append(get_message("PASSWORD_NOT_SET")[0])
        # Reduce timing variation between existing and non-existing users
        hash_password(self.password.data)
        return False
    if not self.user.verify_and_update_password(self.password.data):
        self.password.errors.append(get_message("INVALID_PASSWORD")[0])
        return False
    if requires_confirmation(self.user):
        self.email.errors.append(get_message("CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED")[0])
        return False
    if not self.user.is_active:
        self.email.errors.append(get_message("DISABLED_ACCOUNT")[0])
        return False
    return True
```

and register it as described in other posts:

```
# Setup Flask-Security
app.config['SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES'] = ('username','email')
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore,
                login_form=ExtendedLoginForm)
```

Since email and username are optional now one of them can be used to login. But make sure that both fields are set unique in the DB model.

Answer (score 1):

In an extension, it's possible

https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html

by this setting in config

```
SECURITY_USERNAME_ENABLE = True
```