# How to make Flask-Security login via email or another field?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I am now using Flask-Security to make a login page for my website. However, it can only login via email. I want it to login via both email and cellphone number. I have followed the instructions from this post: [flask-security login via username and not email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827696/flask-security-login-via-username-and-not-email), but it doesn't work. When I input the cellphone number and password, I will receive a message "**Specified user does not exist**". Here is the code of my login form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, HiddenField, BooleanField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length
from flask_security.forms import LoginForm

class MyLoginForm(LoginForm):
    email = StringField('Cellphone or Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(8, 60)])
    password = PasswordField('Passowrd', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(6, 128)])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

And here is the code for my models:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role',
                        secondary=roles_users,
                        backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    cellphone = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False, unique=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
```

I have set `app.config['SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES'] = ['cellphone', 'email']`, and here is the my template for login_user.html:

```
{% from "security/_macros.html" import render_field_with_errors, render_field %}
{%- extends "base.html" %}
{% include "security/_messages.html" %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block contents %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <form action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST" name="login_user_form">
          {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
          {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email, class_="form-control") }}
          {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.password, class_="form-control") }}
          {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.remember) }}
          {{ render_field(login_user_form.next) }}
          {{ render_field(login_user_form.submit, class_="btn btn-primary") }}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I wonder what I should do to make Flask-Security accept either cellphone or email.

Comment: Can you explain or give a stacktrace of what doesn't work exactly ?

Comment: When I input email and password, it works OK. However, when I input cellphone and password, it will display "Specified user does not exist".

Comment: can you show the code you use to verify a user's credentials?

Comment: I use the default method of flask-security. I am new to flask-security and I don't know how to override its login method.

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer is that if you are using Flask-Security 3.0 - it doesn't handle varied input well - in particular, if it believes the input is numeric, it queries the PK using that value and won't try any of the other USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES. You can test this easily by setting your cellphone to have some non-numbers in it (such as 555-1212). Note that an initial '+' sign is still considered numeric by python. Then see if you can log in with that.
If that is the issue - I have improved on that in my maintained fork over at:
https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Security-Too/

Comment: Wow! It works! Thanks jwag! I have changed the format of cellphone number according to your suggestion. Now I can login not only with email but also with cellphone number. I am using Flask-Security 3.0.0. I will try to use your fork to see whether it is more convenient. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the `validate()` function in your LoginForm.
Have a look this example [here](https://github.com/xemedo/flask-angular-security). In this app, you can log in using either username or email. So very similar to your problem.